# Can't seem to call a class in main

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a reference to my class but it seems `to` is not declared.

This means it's undeclared:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time
{
private:
    int sec;
    int mins;
    int hours;
public:
    void setSeconds(int x)
    {
        sec = x;
    }

    int getSeconds()
    {
        return sec;
    }
};

int main()
{
    time to;
    to.setSeconds(10000000);
    cout << to.getSeconds() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error reads:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:10: error: expected ';' before 'to'
     time to;
          ^
main.cpp:29:12: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'time' [-Waddress]
     time to;
            ^
main.cpp:29:12: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
main.cpp:30:5: error: 'to' was not declared in this scope
     to.setSeconds(10000000);
     ^
```

Comment: @chris It is required in C++.

Comment: @chris: because it's required by language rules?

Comment: There are no references here.

Comment: Now taking suggestions for title improvements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::time` is a function in the C++ standard library and, since you're `using namespace std`, that's being used by default instead of your class.

You can't even write `::time` to reference yours, because your compiler's standard library implementation happens to include the old C `::time` as well before wrapping it into namespace `std`.

Use some or all of these suggestions:

- give your class a better, more unique name
- write `class time` to reference your class ([this ensures the *type* `time` is used](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4fc5970d6ac2e5c), but is a poor hack)
- use a namespace yourself to avoid all future ambiguities (this is recommended)

You should also stop `using namespace std` in general to help avoid as much trouble as possible, though it cannot directly aid you in this case.

Comment: *stop `using namespace std`* [doesn't help in this case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a40287725f57777) - seems that `<iostream>` includes `<time.h>` (both in libc++ and libstdc++)

Comment: @AntonSavin Would it be so hard to get rid of the global namespace stuff in C++ headers? Or is it not done for legacy reasons?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: D.5/2 allows it, mostly for legacy yes.

Comment: The name is explicitly reserved by [extern.names] anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Clang give a better error message:

```
time.cpp:29:5: error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'time' in this scope
    time t;
    ^
    class 
/usr/include/time.h:192:15: note: class 'time' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'time' here
extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
              ^
```

It isn't related to `using namespace std`.  Rather the global time function is conflicting.